# sqlalchemy filter_by() got one more argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

```
environment:
    python 3.6.4
    SQLAlchemy==1.2.7
```

I wrote this code and it works.

1.

```
filter_data = session.query(MyClass).filter_by(form_type=form_type).one()
```

and I want to cut function , I wrote below code, but it raise exception.

2.

```
def myfunc(session, instance, **query):

    class_name = type(instance).__name__

    try:
        ins = session.query(class_name).filter_by(query).one()
        ...


myfunc(session, new_data, form_type=form_type)
```

exception is below

```
ins = session.query(class_name).filter_by(query).one()
TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

in function filter_by at query.py of sqlalchemy.orm, I add below code to debug.

```
def filter_by(self, **kwargs):
    l = locals()
    print(f'locals are: {l}')

    ...
```

it shows,

case 1.

```
locals are: {'kwargs': {'form_type': 'TAX'}, 'self': <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x1065d8470>}
```

case 2.

```
locals are: {'kwargs': {'form_type': 'TAX'}, 'self': <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query object at 0x10b7b54a8>}
```

It seems to me the same...
What's the wrong with above two?

Comment: try `cls = instance.__class__` instead of `class_name = type(instance).__name__` and `ins = session.query(cls).filter_by(**query).one()` instead of `ins = session.query(class_name).filter_by(query).one()`, and comment + update your post with any new error message you see.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! My problems are sending object not class_name, and not sending all kwargs ? but what the mean of  TypeError?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
cls = instance.__class__
```

instead of

```
class_name = type(instance).__name__
```

and

```
ins = session.query(cls).filter_by(**query).one()
```

instead of

```
ins = session.query(class_name).filter_by(query).one()
```

- `session.query` expects a sqlalchemy declarative class, not a class name
- `session.query.filter_by` expects variable number of named arguments. since it is an instance method, the first argument is `self`. The filter parameters can be passed as named arguments through dictionary unpacking, however, if the dict itself is passed, it is like two positional arguments are given to the method, `self` & `query`.

Here's a simple example to illustrate this:

```
class Hal(object):
    def hal(self, **kwargs):
        return kwargs

hal = Hal()
hal.hal({'a': 1}) # Throws TypeError
hal.hal(**{'a': 1}) # Returns {'a': 1}
```

Comment: Your explanation was really helpful to me to understand it! Thanks a lot!